# Error al editar datos de una Database Sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Os explico, puedo añadir bien datos a mi database `Sqlite` pero no puedo editarla, os comento.

En mi `RecordatoriosAdapter` tengo el siguiente método:

```
private void editTaskDialog(final Recordatorios recordatorios) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View subView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_recordatorio_layout, null);
    final EditText nameField = (EditText) subView.findViewById(R.id.enter_name);
    final EditText previaField = (EditText) subView.findViewById(R.id.enter_previa);
    final EditText favField = (EditText) subView.findViewById(R.id.enter_fav);
    if (recordatorios != null) {
        nameField.setText(recordatorios.getName());
        previaField.setText(recordatorios.getPrevia());
    }
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setTitle("Edit recordatorios");
    builder.setView(subView);
    builder.create();
    builder.setPositiveButton("EDIT PRODUCT", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            final String name = nameField.getText().toString();
            final String previa = previaField.getText().toString();
            final String fav = favField.getText().toString();
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(name) || TextUtils.isEmpty(previa) || TextUtils.isEmpty(fav)) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Algo salió mal", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                mDatabase.updateProduct(new Recordatorios(recordatorios.getId(), name, previa, fav));
                ActualizaRecyclerView();
            }
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Task cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}
```

Y desde el botón *editar* lo llamo así:

```
editTaskDialog(singleRecordatorios);
```

Y funciona perfectamente, puedo editar los datos, pero, **el problema viene ahora**, estoy intentando cambiar ese método por una `Activity` pero no consigo que funcione correctamente, mi código en la `Activity`

```
public class EditarNota extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static SqliteDatabase mDatabase;
    public static EditText nameField, previaField, favField;
    Button btn1;
    Recordatorios recordatorios;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_editar_nota);

        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);

        nameField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.enter_name);
        previaField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.enter_previa);
        favField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.enter_fav);
        mDatabase = new SqliteDatabase(this);

// cargo los datos
        if (recordatorios != null) {
            nameField.setText(recordatorios.getName());
            previaField.setText(recordatorios.getPrevia());
            favField.setText(recordatorios.getFav());
        }

        // edito
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final String name = nameField.getText().toString();
                final String previa = previaField.getText().toString();
                final String fav = favField.getText().toString();
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(name) || TextUtils.isEmpty(previa) || TextUtils.isEmpty(fav)){
                    Toast.makeText(EditarNota.this, "Hubo un error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else{
                    mDatabase.updateProduct(new Recordatorios(recordatorios.getId(), name, previa, fav));
                    ActualizaRecyclerView();
                    finish();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(mDatabase != null){
            mDatabase.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Y desde el botón *editar* llamo así a la `Activity`

```
Intent intent= new Intent(context, EditarNota.class);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

El problema viene cuando desde la `Activity` `EditarNotas` hago clic en el botón de guardar (`btn1`)  la edición se cierra la aplicación:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int otraprueba.dos.RecyclerViewAdapter.Recordatorios.getId()' on a null object reference

Parece ser que no carga la **ID** al iniciar la `Activity` `EditarNota`

¿Alguien me puede ayudar? Gracias :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el método `editTaskDialog(final Recordatorios recordatorios)`estas pasando como parámetro el objeto `Recordatorios`. Sin embargo, en la actividad `EditarNota` el objeto `Recordatorios` no lo estas iniciando. Pasa como parámetro al iniciar la activity el objeto para después obtenerlo y asignarlo.

**Iniciar la activity**

```
Intent intent= new Intent(context, EditarNota.class);
intent.putExtra("ClaseRecordatorios", singleRecordatorios);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

**Obtener el objeto en la activity**

```
Recordatorios recordatorios;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_editar_nota);

    //obtienes el objeto y lo asignas 
    recordatorios = (Recordatorios) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("ClaseRecordatorios");
    //....
```

Y la clase Recordatorios, implementar serializable

```
public class Recordatorios implements Serializable {
//...
```

Obviamente extendiendo tu adapter, únicamente implementar Serializable

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta @Israel ! pero obtengo dos problemas al compilar, en `EditarNotas` obtengo lo siguiente `Error:(28, 57) error: incompatible types: Serializable cannot be converted to Recordatorios` y en el `Adapter`, muchos errores similares a este `Error:(58, 23) error: no suitable method found for putExtra(String,Recordatorios)
method Intent.putExtra(String,boolean) is not applicable`

Comment: Para pasar el objeto de clase de esa manera la clase `Recordatorios` debe usar `implements Serializable` edito la respuesta agregando eso. El error que tienes en tu código viene de lo que comento, cuando lanzas la activity, declaras `Recordatorios recordatorios;` pero en ningún momento lo estas iniciando o sea es null, el dialog te funciona ya que estas pasando dicha clase como parametro y seguramente este inicializada. Por otra parte puedes usar la instancia de clase directamente.

Comment: Perfecto! Solucionado gracias :) @Israel !